# How to fix Slider on tyche theme wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

When enabling the slider on the tyche theme in wordpress, there ends up beeing a big white space under it, which a can't get rid of.

I've tried editing the slider size with css (copied from internet and changed the size a bit, as I'm pretty new to this and hardly know anything about css ). 
The slider on desktop version looks good then, but on mobile version it is too big and still has the white space under it.

This is the link to the website: www.rhibee.com

This is the css I added:

```
div#main-slider { height: 600px !important; width: 800px !important; }
```

Hoping to find someone who can help me get rid of the white space.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you problem is the slider images. The slider uses the slider image as background and as image tag. Make all the images equal to height and width. Then replace the old images of the slider with the new.

Comment: I tried that, but then the white space just gets bigger. 
I've also just tried with one picture, but that doesn't work either...